# Run a multiple source Dijkstra to the k closest sinks via a Scipy CSR matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy, sparse-matrix, graph-theory

I have a distance matrix `D` on a graph, given as a Scipy CSR matrix. From the `n` vertices in the graph, I have a subset of `m<n` vertices, let's call these *marked*. Now, for each marked vertex `v`, I want to find the `k<m` closest marked vertices `v_1,...,v_k`, where closest is the travel distance according to edges in the graph as given by `D`. Ultimately, this should give me a sparse distance matrix `D'` on only the marked vertices, where each row has `k` entries.

Using the [`scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra.html) package, I can (almost) achieve this goal as follows

```
dijkstra_matrix = dijkstra(csgraph=D, directed=False, indices=marked_vertices)
D' = csr_matrix(dijkstra_matrix[:, marked_vertices])
```

"Almost", because I am computing more than the desired `k` entries per row. Worse, however: if the subset of marked vertices is way smaller than the whole vertex set, this is terribly inefficient: It computes the distance from the marked vertices to *all* vertices in the graph, not only to the marked ones. Hence, I would like to:

(A) Have code similar to the one above, but not only specify the marked vertices as sources, but also als sinks, i.e., compute only the distance matrix on the marked vertices.
(B) Even better: While doing (A), the algorithm could stop with the breadth-first search for each marked vertex that already found `k` closest marked neighbors.

Comment: You want to find the k-NN distance graph for a subset of nodes, where the distances are based on graph traversal instead of point to point?

Comment: Yes, I want the k-NN distance graph solely on the subset and the distances should be given by traversal distances in the larger graph.